# Why Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy doesn't show all the settings

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to verify GPO settings on the Windows Server 2019 machine. To do this, I export GPO settings using PowerShell Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy command:

```
Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy -ReportType Xml -Path gpo.xml
```

And it works BUT it doesn't show all the settings. For example, there is no **SeCreateGlobalPrivilege** setting while it is present in the output of the Secedit command.

Why is that? How can I export all GPO settings with Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any switches or additional actions required. The information is located in ComputerResults > ExtensionData, and the Extension is named Security Settings.

Under that element, there are elements for Account, UserRightsAssignment, and SecurityOptions.

If you are missing this data, it could be due to numerous issues related to enumerating Group Policy, and is not specify to this cmdlet. (gpresult may show the same issue).

`<ExtensionData> <Extension xmlns:q12="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security" xsi:type="q12:SecuritySettings" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings">`